# How to implement MS scanBarCode API in Microsoft Teams extension

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an existing extension app (Node.js)  in MS Teams. I am interested in **[Integration of QR or barcode scanner capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/qr-barcode-scanner-capability)** in it.

- I already have `media` permissions added to the manifest.
- I am using `@microsoft/teams-js` library for the API.

On running the app I am getting this bellow error:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
> at Object. (/Users/dch/Desktop/GitHub/MedxNote/DCH/medxtasks-extension-api/node_modules/@microsoft/teams-js/dist/MicrosoftTeams.min.js:1:227)

Is it feasible to use the API in the extension app?

Or, Do I have to run the API in the web app (Angular) and use that in **TaskModule** in the extension?

Also, Didn’t find any sample application in [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/qr-barcode-scanner-capability)

---

Edit:

**My question after implementation is what is the use case of this API and what's so special about this API,** because it seems to be a normal barcode in any webapp.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some experiments, I am successfully able to build the solution to **Integrate QR or barcode scanner capability** in MS extension.

The approach that I am using is,

- by calling the API in the angular app and,
- providing the endpoint of the app in the extension `Task module WebView`.

#### Manifest Update:

```
"devicePermissions": [
    "media",
],
```

#### Angular App:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-qr-scanner',
    templateUrl: './qr-scanner.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./qr-scanner.component.sass'],
})

export class QrScannerComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}

    displayText = '';
    result = '';

    config: microsoftTeams.media.BarCodeConfig = {
        timeOutIntervalInSec: 30,
    };

    ngOnInit(): void {
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
    }

    onClick() {
        microsoftTeams.media.scanBarCode((error: microsoftTeams.SdkError, decodedText: string) => {
            if (error) {
                if (error.message) {
                    console.log(' ErrorCode: ' + error.errorCode + error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log(' ErrorCode: ' + error.errorCode);
                }
                this.displayText = error.message;
            } else if (decodedText) {
                this.displayText = decodedText;
                console.log(decodedText);
            }
        }, this.config);
    }

    showResult() {
        this.result = this.displayText;
    }
}
```

```
<div style="margin: 10px">
    <div>
        <button (click)="onClick()" class="btn-cm" style="color: #58ef47; margin: 2px">Scan the Code</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button (click)="showResult()" class="btn-cm" style="color: #58ef47; margin: 2px">Get Result</button>
    </div>
</div>

<mat-label>{{ result }}</mat-label>
```

#### Extension App (NodeJS):

```
....
 return {
    task: {
      type: 'continue',
      value: {
         height: 600,
         width: 600,
         title: 'Task module WebView',
         url: `https://example.com/qrscanner`
      }
    }
};
```

For more details follow the docs from Microsoft ([Integrate QR or barcode scanner capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/qr-barcode-scanner-capability#code-snippet))